# Using Azure data factory with Odata source from Microsoft Dynamics Marketing

Tags: azure, odata, azure-data-factory

I am having some trouble understanding the URL which I should specify while importing data into Azure Blob storage from the OData feed on Dynamics Marketing(MDM), using Azure Data Factory.

I created a Odata Linked Service to import data and within this, for the path, I specified the location of the Odata URL specified within the OData settings for MDM. I get the below error.

Mashup operation failed. Error message from Mashup execution : ErrorCode=FailedMashupOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message='Type=System.NotSupportedException,Message=The given data source reference cannot test the connection. FailureReason: InvalidDataSourceLocationUrl.,Source=Microsoft.Data.Mashup,',Source=,'.

Answer (score 1):

InvalidDataSourceLocationUrl error code shows it's wrong url.

The 'path' in odata data set should be a relative path, which works together with the root path in OData linked service.

E.g. if the odata endpoint your want is:

```
http: //services.odata.org/odata/odata.svc/Products?$select=Name,%20Description&$top=5
```

the linked service should be:

```
{
  "name": "ODataLinkedService",
  "properties": {
    "type": "OData",
    "typeProperties": {
      "url": "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc",
      "authenticationType": "Anonymous"
    }
  }
}
```

and the dataset:

```
{
  "name": "ODataDataset",
  "properties": {
    "type": "ODataResource",
    "typeProperties": {
      "path": "Products"
    },
    "linkedServiceName": "ODataLinkedService",
    "structure": [],
    "availability": {
      "frequency": "Hour",
      "interval": 1
    },
    "external": true,
    "policy": {
      "retryInterval": "00:01:00",
      "retryTimeout": "00:10:00",
      "maximumRetry": 3
    }
  }
}
```

and the query in Pipeline:

```
"?$select=Name, Description&$top=5"
```

Referenced by doc :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-odata-connector